What is the dead address on Solana for burning tokens?
I was making a research on a meme token on Solana and I saw that the dev sent about 13% of the token supply to this address 1nc1nerator11111111111111111111111111111111. I want to know if that is a dead address and if it belongs to Sol-incinerator. Also, I want to be sure that it means that the dev burnt some % of the supply and doesn't have access to the tokens anymore.
Thank you.

This question is similar to: Is there an official burn address on Solana?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

On Solana you need to actually burn tokens.
You can do this using solburner.fun
1nc1nerator11111111111111111111111111111111 is an address that would not have a private key hence cannot be used by any user to transfer the tokens any further.

Ok thank you. So, sending a token to 1nc1nerator11111111111111111111111111111111 still kind of does same function as burning right?
